# Looping through image array and moving them - Laravel

Tags: php, image, image-processing, laravel-4

I have a form which has 5 file inputs to create an array of images.

When processing, I wish to loop through the images and process them.

```
$images = Input::get('images');
// image proccessing
foreach ($images as $image) {
  print_r($image);
}
```

That will output the file name, but If I call the move function on the $image variable I get "method move called on string".

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 0):

```
You should be doing something like this 

       $input = Input::file('files'); //get file as input
        //check if input has file 
        if ($input){
            foreach($input as $key){
            //loop through file and perform action...
              $array = Image::file_upload($key, 'file', 'Images');
              // I assume you have your method for upload like the above
              $key = $array['filename'];
              print_r($key);    
            }
        }
        $this->image->save($input); //save to db file name.
```